# PHP subtracting and adding time

Tags: php

I'm looking for an answer for few hours now, but I can't find one.

I'm writing simple script. User set work start time, and end time.

this is my code:

```
$grand=0;
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT StartTime,EndTime FROM tblWeekSchedule WHERE FCode='101'";
$query = safe_query($query);
$gquery = gather_info_in_array($query);
foreach ($gquery as $z) {
    $s = $z['StartTime'];
    $e = $z['EndTime'];
    $tutal = date_create($s)->diff(date_create($e))->format('%H:%I');
    $grand+=$tutal;
}
echo $grand;
```

the output is always whole number example 10 .. . i want to make it like this example 10:30

im a newbie in programming.. ang willing to learn.. Thank you in advance

Comment: Convert to seconds with strtotime() and subtract in seconds, then convert back to date format.

Comment: what shoud i convert $grand?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your code but it seems as you use start and end time to get elapsed time? And add that to grand? So.. maybe: `$tutal = strtotime($e)-strtotime($s)` this means tutal (and grand) is in seconds. So you need to replace echo $grand with: `echo date("H:i", $grand);` again.. maybe :-)

Comment: Wait.. what is this supposed to do?? `format('%H:%I');` hours in 24 format, and daylight savings integer? That is what capital I is... maybe that is your problem?

Comment: Lol.. just noticed I made the same mistake as you with capital I. Edited my comment :-)

Comment: i change it to `i` but the output is still 10 it should be 10:30.... im using military time

Comment: Strtotime(), does that work? What format is `$z['EndTime'];` and start time in?

Comment: @VPrince any luck with my answer?

Comment: 00:00 it look like this .. im still searching..

Comment: Have you tried my answer below?

Comment: See here, I have simplified the code slightly because I don't have database and do not need the foreach, but the basics is the same https://3v4l.org/9Jjpr

Answer (score 0):

Convert to unix timestamp.

Simple eg;

```
$n = time();
echo $n; // 1465977786, (when I ran it.
$t = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $n);
echo $t; //2016-06-15 13:33:06

$x = 1465976585;
$t = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $x);
echo $t; //2016-06-15 13:13:05

$t = $n - $x;
echo $t; //1201
```

1201 seconds difference between the two times. Now simple math of divide by 60 to extract hour min, etc.

The problem you will run into will be when the date changes, ie. midnight. Say 6:00 pm and 2:00am. Hence it is better to save CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to MySQL, that way you have all the necessary info in one field.

To get unix timestamp from MySQL;

`$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`StartTime`),UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`EndTime`) FROM tblWeekSchedule WHERE FCode='101'";`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the last line: `$grand+=$tutal;`

This line is doing a numerical addition between `$grand` and `$tutal`.

However, `$tutal` is not numeric -- it's a string. It would look something like `10:30`, but if you do a `+=` on that, PHP will convert it into an number before adding. This conversion will result in the number `10`, because the `:` is non-numeric, and so PHP drops everything after the colon to do the addition.

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do by adding them to `$grand`. Are you trying to add up the number of hours?

You say you're trying to add the hours and minutes.

The fact is that you're over-complicating it be using the date objects. Just use unix timestamps, and you can subtract them easily without needing to use functions like `DateTime::diff()`.

here's a better solution:

```
foreach ($gquery as $z) {
    $s = $z['StartTime'];  //I assume that StartTime is a unix timestamp? if not, convert it to one on this line.
    $e = $z['EndTime'];    //I assume that EndTime is a unix timestamp? if not, convert it to one on this line.

    $tutal = $e - $s;      // unix timestamps are integers, so can be subtracted easily to get the time difference.
    $grand += $tutal;      // $grand will now be the total number of seconds of all your time differences.
}

$grand_minutes = floor($grand / 60);        // get the number of minutes (ignore any left-over seconds.
$grand_hours = floor($grand_minutes / 60);  // get the number of hours (ignore any left-over minutes)
$remainder_minutes = $grand_minutes % 60;   // now we get the left-over minutes.

echo "Total time: {$grand_hours}:{$remainder_minutes}\n";
```

(this is assuming `$z['StartTime']` and `$z['EndTime`']` are unix timestamps; if they aren't, convert them to timestamp format ahead of this code)

Comment: yes i'm trying to add the elapsed hours and minutes

Answer (score 0):

I created an answer of my comments so that it is easier to see what I meant.
This will calculate everything in seconds, $tutal and $grand will be integer values thus making calculations easier.

```
$grand=0;
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT StartTime,EndTime FROM tblWeekSchedule WHERE FCode='101'";
$query = safe_query($query);
$gquery = gather_info_in_array($query);
foreach ($gquery as $z) {
    $s = $z['StartTime'];
    $e = $z['EndTime'];
    $tutal = strtotime($e)-strtotime($s);
    $grand+=$tutal;
}
echo date("H:i", $grand);
```

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

check this logic.

```
$date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+1 month", strtotime('2016-01-01')));
echo $date;
//output 2016-02-01
```

Comment: I don't think this is what OP is looking for.